# Is it possible to store BigDecimal 0.000 in Oracle with JPA

Tags: java, jpa-2.0, eclipselink, oracle11gr2, ojdbc

I have the following property on a JPA entity:

```
@NotNull
@DecimalMin("0.000")
@DecimalMax("1.000")
@Digits(integer = 1, fraction = 3)
@Column(nullable = false, precision = 4, scale = 3)
private BigDecimal confidence;

public BigDecimal getConfidence() {
    return this.confidence;
}

public void setConfidence(BigDecimal confidence) {
    this.confidence = confidence;
}
```

If confidence is set to "0.000", eg: setConfidence(new BigDecimal("0.000")); and then the entity is persisted to the database and then fetched back from the database, the value fetched loses its precision and scale and is simply 0.

The database schema is created by JPA/Eclipselink when the web application is deployed.

My environment is EclipseLink 2.3.2.v20111125-r10461, Oracle 11g R2, Oracle JDBC thin driver OJDBC 1.6.

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference in the database between 0 and 0.000, so it should not matter.

It should not matter is Java either.  If you want to print the bigdecimal with 3 digits, then just use a printer that does this.

If you issue is the equals() method in Java, then don't use this, use compareTo() instead.

http://www.opentaps.org/docs/index.php/How_to_Use_Java_BigDecimal:_A_Tutorial